# i can not add two characters in my num1 parameter in my calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I can not add two characters in my `num1` 
 parameter in my calculator plz help me to solve it.

Please look at it if anyone can find the solution. If I put any condition for that it takes `num1` value in `num2` for operation. for example, if I will take `(89*2)` it will perform `(89*89)`. That's how it goes....

```html
<html>  
 <head>  
  <script>  
    
  var num1;  
  var num2;  
  var result;  
  var operations;  
    
  function getDisplay(digit)
  {  

   if (display.value == "0" || display.value != "")
   { 
    display.value = digit;
   }  
   else  
   {  
    display.value = display.value + digit;

   }  
  }  
  function clr()
  {  
   display.value = "0";  
   //uprDisplay.value = "";   
  } 
  function addition()
  {  
   operation = "+";  
   num1 = parseInt(display.value); 
   display.value = num1 + operation;  
   //uprDisplay.value = num1 + operation; 
  }   
  function subtraction(){  
     
   operation = "-";  
   num1 = parseInt(display.value);
   display.value = num1 + operation;  
   //uprDisplay.value = num1 + operation;  
  } 
  function multiplication()
  { 
   operation = "*";  
   num1 = parseInt(display.value); 
   display.value = num1 + operation;  
   //uprDisplay.value = num1 + operation;  
  }  
  function division()
  {     
   operation = "/";  
   num1 = parseInt(display.value);  
   display.value = num1 + operation;  
   //uprDisplay.value = num1 + operation; 
  }  
  function equalto()
  {  
     
   num2 = parseInt(display.value);  
   
   if (operation == "+")  
   {  
    result = num1 + num2;  
   }  
   else if (operation == "*")
   {
    result = num1 * num2;  
   }  
   else if (operation == "-")
   { 
    result = num1 - num2; 
   }    
   else if (operation == "/")
   {  
    result = num1 / num2;  
   }  

   //display.value = result;  
   display.value = num1 + operation + num2 + " = " + result;  

  }  
    
    
  </script>  
 </head>  
 <body>    

  <form name="calculator"> 
   <table>
    <!-- <tr>
     <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="uprDisplay" id="uprDisplay" style="text-align:right;" disabled="disabled" value=""/></td>
    </tr> -->
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="display" id="display" style="text-align:right;" disabled="disabled" value="0"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="button" id="button" onclick="getDisplay(this.value)" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="seven" value="7"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button" onclick="getDisplay(this.value)" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="eight" value="8"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button" onclick="getDisplay(this.value)" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="nine" value="9"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button" onclick="division()" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="div" value="/"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="getDisplay(this.value)" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="four" value="4"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="getDisplay(this.value)" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="five" value="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="getDisplay(this.value)" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="six" value="6"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="multiplication()" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="mult" value="*"/></td>
     
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="getDisplay(this.value)" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="one" value="1"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="getDisplay(this.value)" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="two" value="2"/></td> 
     <td><input type="button" onclick="getDisplay(this.value)" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="three" value="3"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="subtraction()" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="sub" value="-"/></td>
     
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="clr()" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="clear" value="C"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="getDisplay(this.value)" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="zero" value="0"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="equalto()" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="equal" value="="/></td>
     <td><input type="button" onclick="addition()" style="height: 30px; width: 100%;" name="add" value="+"/></td>
    </tr>
   </table> 
     
  </form>
  
 </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: change `if (display.value == "0" || display.value != "")` to `if (display.value === "0" || display.value === "")`

Comment: Not working it operates num1 + num1 and also not clearing screen for next calculation

Comment: @SwetaParmar the fix suggested by Zeek is helping, it just isn't the whole story. When you press =, you do "parseInt" on the _whole_ display, which is, e.g. 89*2...how can you parse all of that as a single integer? You can't. As per spec (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), as soon as it encounters the * it ignores that, and all the characters which follow, and just reads num2 as 89. You need to parse the string into the different pieces and just get the bit _after_ the *. Also consider how to process more than one * e.g. 89*2*20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple, change

`if (display.value == "0" || display.value != "")`

to

`if (display.value === "0" || display.value === "")`

**EDIT**

Okay, there are more bugs.
So, you see, at the press of each operation, you are changing `display.value` to the **String** `num1 + operation`, and in the `equalTo` method, you are trying to `parseInt` this `num1 + operation` **String** which will not produce desired results. Instead, split the **String** using `split(operation)` which will result in a array of **String**  containing the 2 numbers, and use `parseInt()` over the second number (index 1).

In short,in the method `equalTo`,
change

`num2 = parseInt(display.value);`

to

`num2 = parseInt(display.value.split(operation)[1]);`

Comment: but it still not clearing screen when next operation is starts :(

Comment: @SwetaParmar inside the `getDisplay()` add `if(result !== undefined) { clr(); result = undefined ;` as the first if case

Comment: Or you can take a pencil and paper, and try to execute your code manually, and understand yourself, what you need to do :) . I would recommend this approach.

Comment: @ ZeekHuge I added feature for  positive to negative and vice versa this is my code. if(display.value > 0)
   {
    Math.abs(display.value);
   }
   else if(display.value < 0)
   {
    display.value * (-1);
   }    but not working